# Conteúdo do site cobrindo barra de navegação

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho uma barra de navegação no topo de uma página, porém o conteúdo do meu site cobre a barra de navegação a partir do momento que uso a barra de rolagem. Como posso resolver isto?

***Código***:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}

div.topbar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 0.3px solid #000;
  background-color: #181818;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 56px;
  padding-bottom: 56px;
}

h2 {
  color: #ddd;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 #000, 0 1px #000, 1px 0 #000, 0 -1px #000;
}

p {
  color: #ddd;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 0.3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 1px;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}

nav ul li:active {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#teste">Teste</a></li>
      <li><a href="#teste">Teste</a></li>
      <li><a href="#teste">Teste</a></li>
      <li><a href="#teste">Teste</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="testdiv1imagem" style="position: relative;">
      <img src="http://bsnscb.com/data/out/40/40070819-coding-wallpapers.jpg" width="900" style="filter: blur(6px) brightness(70%);">
    </div>
    <h2 id="home">Inicio</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
      elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
      dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
      et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
      sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
      qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
      ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Tenta colocar `z-index` maior que 0 no `.topbar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta acresccentar a propriedade z-index na sua classe `topbar`.

A propriedade z-index especifica a ordem de pilha de um elemento, ou seja, qual elemento deve estar "na frente" do outro. Parecido com a estrutura de camadas do Photoshop

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  position: relative;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0px auto 0px auto;
}

div.topbar {
  position: fixed;
  height: 56px;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-bottom: 0.3px solid #000;
  background-color: #181818;
  z-index: 2;
}

.container {
  padding-top: 56px;
  padding-bottom: 56px;
}

h2 {
  color: #ddd;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 #000, 0 1px #000, 1px 0 #000, 0 -1px #000;
}

p {
  color: #ddd;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border: 0.3px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 1px;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}

nav ul li:active {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar">
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#teste">Teste</a></li>
      <li><a href="#teste">Teste</a></li>
      <li><a href="#teste">Teste</a></li>
      <li><a href="#teste">Teste</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="testdiv1imagem" style="position: relative;">
      <img src="http://bsnscb.com/data/out/40/40070819-coding-wallpapers.jpg" width="900" style="filter: blur(6px) brightness(70%);">
    </div>
    <h2 id="home">Inicio</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing
      elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum
      dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
      et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur
      sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
      quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa
      qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi
      ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  </div>
</main>
```